# VB.net How can I check if two brushes are the same or same color?

Tags: vb.net, brushes

How can I find out if two brushes are equal

```
tColor1 = New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF89DE93")
tColor2 = New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF89DE93")
tColor3 = Brushes.LightGray
```

How can I compare these burshes and get true for tColor1 = tColor2 and false for tColor1 = tColor3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim tColor1 As SolidColorBrush = CType(New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF89DE93"), SolidColorBrush)
    Dim tColor2 As SolidColorBrush = CType(New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF89DE93"), SolidColorBrush)
    Dim tColor3 = Brushes.LightGray

    Dim test As Boolean


    test = tColor1.Color = tColor2.Color 'True
    test = tColor1.Color = tColor3.Color 'False
```

Comment: This works but is there not a way to compare without converting each item I want to compare? If I don't find a better option or a better explanation, I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: What do you mean be converting? CType simply casts, it doesn't convert. Or do you mean using the BrushConverter().ConvertFrom call?

Comment: sorry, mistaken choice of words. I mean cast.